# How to pass the image file in HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions

I want to pass the image content into `HttpRequestMessage`. I was trying the below method.

```
public  async Task  UploadImage()
{
    string Imgpath = @"d:\Dummy.jpg";
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();

    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(Imgpath);
    requestMessage.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
}

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage,
    TraceWriter traceWriter)
{
        var imagecontent = httpRequestMessage.Content;
        string Testcontent = imagecontent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        // Testcontent value is coming like this "����qExif"
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(Testcontent));

        // Here i am getting error the input is not a valid Base-64 string 
        // as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, 
        // or an illegal character among the padding character.     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting the data to base64 string before passing it to the HTTPRequest.

```
private string ConvertImageToBase64(byte[] imageBytes)
{
     string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
     return base64String;
}
```

Try something like this to convert it to base64 string and then set the content as the string obtained.

```
requestMessage.Content = new StreamContent(base64string);
```

PS : You can alternatively pass the image data as binary with a `multipart/form-data` request and then decode at the other side respectively.

Comment: doesn't even need to be multipart/form-data. In fact you can simply send the image as raw binary content in an HTTP request. This makes reading it on the server side super simple.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can find some examples on Google, I wouldn't do it at all. Azure already has a blob storage service. [It has also this use case on its getting started guide.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#upload-blobs-to-a-container)
Instead of uploading the file using an HTTP function, I'd upload it to Azure Blob Storage using its client and add a trigger for it, if needed.

I've already done something like this on Amazon to handle a form with file upload. In my particular case, I submit the form in a "draft" state, upload the file directly to S3 and then update the submission state (I could also have done it using AWS lambda).